# Pyspark : Query self dataframe to create a new column

Tags: pyspark

I have the following dataset in pyspark

| Id | Sub |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Mat |
| 1 | Phy |
| 1 | Sci |
| 2 | Bio |
| 2 | Phy |
| 2 | Sci |

I want to create a df similar to the one below

| Id | Sub | HaMat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mat | 1 |
| 1 | Phy | 1 |
| 1 | Sci | 1 |
| 2 | Bio | 0 |
| 2 | Phy | 0 |
| 2 | Sci | 0 |

How do I do this in pyspark ?

```
def hasMath(studentID,df):
    return df.filter(col('Id') == studentID & col('sub') = 'Mat' ).count()
```

df = df.withColumn("hasMath",hasMath(F.col('id'),df1))

But this doesn't seem to work. IS there a better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collect_list` over a window and `expr` (for Spark 2.4+) to get the list of subjects for each `ID` and to filter for `Mat`.

The `size` function gets the count of the array.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window().partitionBy("Id")

df.withColumn("list", F.collect_list(col("Sub")).over(w))\
  .withColumn("hasMath", F.size(F.expr("filter(list, x -> x == 'Mat')")))\
  .drop("list").show()
```

Output:

```
+---+---+-------+
| Id|Sub|hasMath|
+---+---+-------+
|  1|Phy|      1|
|  1|Mat|      1|
|  1|Sci|      1|
|  2|Phy|      0|
|  2|Bio|      0|
|  2|Sci|      0|
+---+---+-------+
```